# DataTables warning (table id = 'example-advanced'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable while using treetable and datatable at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, treetable

**DataTables warning (table id = 'example-advanced'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable while using treetable and datatable at the same time. Here is my code:**

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src='jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src="jquery.treetable.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#example-advanced").treetable({ expandable: true });
</script>            
<script>
  $('#example-advanced').dataTable( {
    "bSort": false
  } );
</script>
```

Actually I wanted to get rid of the sorting part of the datatable coz it was giving error in treetable display so i want the sorting part from the datatable out and keep other functions like search and pagination. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code before initialize the table. It destroys the previous table if exists. Make sure to replace the class name with your class name.

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true
        }).fnDestroy();
```

If you are using Charisma themes. Please go to js/charisma.js and add above code just before the below code segment starts.

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-12'i><'col-md-12 center-block'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });
```